# Flask-MQTT disconnects after 'Socket error on client <unknown>' while running on uWSGI NGINX

Tags: nginx, flask, mqtt, uwsgi

I have a setup where I use [Flask-MQTT](https://flask-mqtt.readthedocs.io/) to connect my python Flask API to a Mosquitto broker. Whenever I run the Flask API with the development server all is well. But whenever I spin it up for production (using wsgi+nginx), the connection with Mosquitto is made, but everytime i try to publish something i get the following error:

```
Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

My app.ini has the processes configured to 1 (`processes = 1`)

My mosquitto.config has the allow_anonymous flag set to trye (`allow_anonymous true`)

I can't really seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here...

**Update:**
So what i think is happening is that the Flask-uwsgi application is trying to connect to mosquitto more than once. There is a master process that connects with Mosquitto on initialize. Then there is a second process that is being used whenever input is given on the Flask app. I'm not sure, but I think Mosquitto only wants one connection at the time, therefor erroring on the second. So now i either need to:

A) Configure Mosquitto in a way that it accepts multiple connection from the same device

B) Configure Flask in a way that wil only use one single process (configuring `processes = 1` is not enough, it will still spawn two processes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turns I could've read that the whole multiple processes wouldn't work from the start at the official Flask-MQTT documentation. It sais right there in think letters:

> Flask-MQTT is currently not suitable for the use with multiple worker
>   instances.

So I looked at my uwsgi `app.ini` file again closely and actually the answer is quite simple. I turned out i had a like in there `master = true`.. after I removed that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

99% of the time, a "`Socket error on client <unknown>`" is an authentication error. I don't know Flask, so I don't know where to point you at, but something in your code is either trying to pass a username/password that is not defined to Mosquitto, or its trying a TLS connection with an cert that Mosquitto doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have double checked the username/password and TLS is disabled. Since the authentication is going correctly when I launch the program without uwsgi, I don't think that could be it..

Comment: @Yonker - Then I would look closer at what uwsgi is doing on the connnect.  I've been working with Mosquitto for five years now, and every single time I get this error, it has always come down to authentication.

Comment: Could it be Mosquitto only accepts one connection per device? If so, is there a way to configure it to allow more than one connection?

Comment: If you set the ``clientId`` field, it will only honor one connection....you can do multiple Publish and Subscribe's with that one connection though.

Comment: I really thought that'd do the trick. I just learned how i could set the MQTT_CLIENT_ID in Flask-MQTT... But unfortunately it doesn't work :(